# how to get the different tag values when receiving response from an xml file

Tags: php, xml

i have an xml file and a php file.i have received a result from an the xml file but i am not being able to get the different values of the tags.what i want is the data from individual tags.Any idea how to do it?
Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<user>
<id>1</id>
<username>neem99</username>
<password>dbhcasvc</password>
<email>vgwdevwe@hfvuejd.com</email>
</user>
</users>
```

Sample php file:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath( $dom );
echo var_dump($xp);
$col = $xp->query( $query );
echo var_dump($col);
$array = array();
if( $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node) echo $node->nodeValue
}


result :   1 neem99 dbhcasvc vgwdevwe@hfvuejd.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; @$doc->load('yourFileName.xml');
$user = $doc->getElementsByTagName('user');
foreach($user as $u){
  echo 'nodeName:'.$u->nodeName.'; nodeValue:'.$u->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows to use Xpath expressions that return scalar values. `string()` casts a list of nodes to a string by returning the text content of the first node.

Demo:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// get first user id
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(/users/user/id)'));

//iterate all user nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/users/user') as $user) {
    // get its username
    var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(username)', $user));
}
```